# Scroll WebView não aparece

Tags: java, android, webview

Criei minha primeira aplicação no android sendo que foi (WebView) mas quando entro no aplicativo, meu site fica fixo dentro, sem scroll.

Meu código é:

```
package com.sirseni.simpleandroidwebviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://meulink.com/");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

    // Use When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://meulink.com/")) {
                return false;

            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Layout: `activity_main.xml`

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/myWebView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

Comment: Como está o seu arquivo de layout?

Comment: `<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que seu `WebView` está definido para não haver `scroll`. Você tem que remover a linha `android:scrollbars="none"` do seu *WebView *.

Veja como deve ficar:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/myWebView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Veja as definições do atributo `scrollbars`:

- `android:scrollbars="vertical"`: habilita *scroll* na vertical
- `android:scrollbars="horizontal"`:  habilita *scroll* na horizontal
- `android:scrollbars="none"`: desabilita *scroll*

Comment: Estou com o seguinte problema agora, quando mudo a posição do celular, o webview da reload e volta pra página de login, você sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: @EvertonGouveia sugiro que você faça outra pergunta, pois nada tem a ver com essa. Mas já adiantando, parece ser uma coisa simples de resolver.